# Angular10 - [(ngModel)] and (ngModelChange) don't read the value after it's saved to db

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel, angular10

Based on what it is selected on this field, I want to fill with data the Tasks field below.

```
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Position</mat-label>
      <mat-select [(ngModel)]="position" (ngModelChange)="change(position)" multiple formControlName="position">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let position of positionArray" [value]="position">
          {{position}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

This is the Tasks field:

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Tasks</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="tasks">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let res of tasksItems" [value]="res">
        {{res}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Typescript code is as below:

```
  private tasksItems= [];

  change(position) {

    if (position == "IT") {
      this.tasksItems= ["one", "two"];
    }
    else if (position == "Design") {
      this.tasksItems= ["three", "four"];
    }
    else {
      this.tasksItems= [];
    }
```

Edit: This is the positionArray in ts. The values are stored in database and the change(position) method works fine. The problem is the field Tasks doesn't get the value that is stored and I am assuming it has something to do with [(ngModel)].

```
   positionArray: string[] = ['IT', 'Design'];
```

> Data is stored to database. But the problem is [(ngModel)] doesn't read the data (when I want to edit the field). Can someone explain to me why and how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you properly write loop in ngFor, in question is *let positionof positionArray* but it has to be *let position of positionArray*. And can you share your *positionArray* array?

Comment: Also, try to *console.log* your *position* in your *change(position)* function and see if you have values that you use in if statement.

Comment: Do you have a variable `position` on your component? Otherwise the mat-select can't work. And if you do have, the `position` you are declaring in the ngFor hides that one, and `position` on your component is never changed from its default value.

Comment: @fredrik I do have a variable position, do you have any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use `ngModel` if you are already using `formControlName`.
I can't see the whole code but I assume you have something like `[formGroup]="form"` on the form element which would bind to the FormGroup in your ts file.

As long as your `form.position` form control is updated, it should reflect in your template.
If you are using reactive form controls try removing `[(ngModel)]="position"` and make sure the form control is set correctly in your ts file.

**Edit**
Also, try changing your template variable names. `position` seems to be used for different variables.
try:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let pos of positionArray" [value]="pos">
  {{pos}}
</mat-option>
```

Comment: Im using [(ngModel)]="position" for binding data to the tasks field, values of the Tasks field on create change based on what it's selected on Position field... if I remove [(ngModel)] the binding doesnt work

Comment: can you share a complete example of your code? currently it looks like you are using ReactiveFormsModule (FormControl, FormGroup, etc.) but it's not clear where the position variable is declared